# Script engine turning integers to strings

Tags: java, scriptengine

I'm using the javax ScriptEngine for a project. The actual call looks like:

```
public static Object runFunction(String function, Object[] arguments) throws ScriptException {
    RHINO_SCRIPT_ENGINE.put("value", arguments);
    return RHINO_SCRIPT_ENGINE.eval(function);
}
```

whereas the variable `arguments` contains 2 objects of the type `Integer` (1 and 2) and the variable `function` contains the function to evaluate `"value[0] + value[1]"`

In my understanding with the given arguments, the evaluated function should return the int value `3` instead it's doing a string concatenation and returns `"12"`

I'm clearly setting an array of Integers to the argument `value`. Can anyone tell me why the script engine is handling it like a String array anyway?

Comment: what does it say when you run the same code with the funcion "typeof value[0]"?

Comment: @Kaddath I didn't think of that.The type is `object` I guess that is why the engine will look at it as a String?

Comment: maybe it is constructed with `String()`, which outputs "Object" when asked for type. Maybe try to walk the object properties with a loop, it might also be an engine custom type where you can get the integer value from a property